# Applesauce as a substitution

Tags: substitutions

When a recipe calls for sugar and oil or butter which one can applesauce be substituted for and what is the ratio?

Answer (score 2):

Applesauce can substitute for either sugar or oil. Usually it is used in replacement for oil as an ingredient for keeping the item moist - banana bread, etc. It isn't a good substitute for butter since it doesn't have anything close to the same taste.

As for ratios:
1:1 as a vegetable oil substitute.

1:1 for sugar if the apple sauce is sweetened. If natural you may need to add sugar. You will need to adjust the amount of liquid down in the recipe to account for the applesauce liquid you are adding.

Comment: I did experimenting with muffins many, many years ago, and I never had good luck with replacing *all* of the oil with applesauce.  I typically left 1/4 to 1/3 of the oil in the original recipe.  It's possible that other types of baking are more forgiving.